# C# WPF Use multi image source ControlTemplate with Button.Tag

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, controltemplate

I have a problem on the using ControlTemplate in Button. I would like to create a button with image and text. When mouse over the button, the image change. I use the Button.Tag to pass the image source. But I need to pass two image sources. Is it possible to create a list of image source in Button.Tag and select in the ControlTemplate? Thanks you.

```
<Style x:Key="myBtnStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Image x:Name="myImg" Source="{TemplateBinding Tag[0]}" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
                    <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
                </StackPanel>

                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Setter TargetName="myImg" Property="Source" Value="{TemplateBinding Tag[1]}" />
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

```
<Button Content="Click" Style="{StaticResource myBtnStyle}">
    <Button.Tag>
      <ImageSource>/img/usb_white.png</ImageSource>
      <ImageSource>/img/usb_gray.png</ImageSource>
    </Button.Tag>
</Button>
```

Comment: Please don't use `Tag`. It doesn't have a descriptive name (thus it's confusing for other developers) and you have no control over its data type. You can create an [attached property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/attached-properties-overview#custom-attached-properties-) instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set the `Tag` property to an `ImageSource[]` using the `<x:Array>` element:

```
<Button Content="Click" Style="{StaticResource myBtnStyle}">
    <Button.Tag>
        <x:Array Type="ImageSource">
            <BitmapImage UriSource="Images/Buldingimage2.jpeg" />
            <BitmapImage UriSource="Images/words.jpg" />
        </x:Array>
    </Button.Tag>
</Button>
```

You also need to replace the `TemplateBindings` in the template with bindings to `TemplatedParent`:

```
<Style x:Key="myBtnStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Image x:Name="myImg" Source="{Binding Tag[0], RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
                    <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
                </StackPanel>

                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Setter TargetName="myImg" Property="Source" Value="{Binding Tag[1], RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" />
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: Thank you. That is exactly what I want ^.^

Answer (score 0):

```
   <Style x:Key="btn_img" TargetType="Button">
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black"/>
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="3"/>
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0"/>
        <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Medium"/>
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="12"/>
        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>

        <Setter Property="Background" Value="WhiteSmoke"/>

        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">

                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="5*"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ContentPresenter Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="2 0 0 0">
                            </ContentPresenter>
                            <ContentControl HorizontalAlignment="Left" Grid.Column="1" Content="{TemplateBinding Tag}" Margin="0 0 2 0"/>
                        </Grid>

                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource b_blue}"/>
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#fff"/>
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Gray"/>
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#fff"/>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
```